# DynamoDB Array of Array of strings schema

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I'm looking for assistance on how I can achieve the schema below into my dynamodb database.

Example of my JSON

```
var users = [{
    userId: 123,
    userName: "John Smith",
    additionalInfomation: [
      ["favoriteColor", "blue"], 
      ["hobbies", "ping-pong"]
    ]
}]
```

This is what I have so far to achieve the `userId` and `userName` schema. I'm having trouble setting up `additionalInfomation` part.

```
  const params = {
    AttributeDefinitions: [
      {
        AttributeName: 'userId',
        AttributeType: 'N'
      },
      {
        AttributeName: 'userName',
        AttributeType: 'S'
      },
      {
        AttributeName: 'additionalInformation',
        AttributeType: <NEED HELP HERE> // <-------------------- ?????
      }
    ],
    KeySchema: [
      {
        AttributeName: 'userId',
        KeyType: 'HASH'
      },
      {
        AttributeName: 'userName',
        KeyType: 'RANGE'
      },
      {
        AttributeName: 'additionalInformation',
        KeyType: <NEED HELP HERE> // <-------------------- ?????
      }
    ],
    ProvisionedThroughput: {
      ReadCapacityUnits: 1,
      WriteCapacityUnits: 1
    },
    TableName: 'USERS',
    StreamSpecification: {
      StreamEnabled: false
    }
  };
  // Call DynamoDB to create the table
  ddb.createTable(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('Error', err);
    } else {
      console.log('Table Created', data);
    }
  });
```

Need help setting the `additionalInformation` schema up. Please excuse my ignorance if this isn't the right approach. Still learning dynamoDB and the aws doc isn't quite helpful for a beginner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this use case, I recommend that you choose either `userId` or `userName` as your `HASH` key (aka partition key) for your table, assuming that either of this attributes will uniquely identify the user. `RANGE` key (aka sort key) are beneficial when you have several items associated with one partition key, c.f. artists and song titles in the [Primary Key](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.CoreComponents.html) paragraph of the DynamoDB user guide. Consequently, this means that you only need to specify one attribute in the `AttributeDefinitions` and `KeySchema`.

Furthermore, I recommend that you omit the `additionalInformation` from your schema based on the assumption that you will neither use that information as partition key nor a sort key.

Instead, you can add them as two separate attributes to individual items when calling [putItem()](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#putItem-property) or [updateItem](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#updateItem-property) (or the corresponding [put()](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html#put-property) and [update()](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html#update-property) functions if you use the DynamoDB [DocumentClient](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html)).

```
const params = {
  Item: {
   "userId": {
     N: "123"
    }, 
   "userName": {
     S: "dummy"
    }, 
   "favoriteColor": {
     S: "blue"
    },
   "hobbies": {
     SS: ["ping-pong", "another hobby"]
    }
  }, 
  TableName: "USERS"
 };
 const putItemPromise = dynamodb.putItem(params).promise()
```

Note, in the example above I have specified `favoriteColor` as `S`, i.e. a single string, but the `hobbies` as `SS` meaning that it is a array of strings. This may or may not what you want, but since the attribute name is "hobbies" (and not "hobby"), I figured that it would make sense to allow more than one.

Comment: I appreciate your knowledge about the HASH and RANGE key. But there's a reason why I needed it as a type of `[["key", "value"], ["key", "value"]]`. Can you update your answer to allow for that use case? Each nested array will always have a size of two and both are strings. Empty string is okay

Comment: This is not supported AFAIK. Maybe you can implement a workaround by using a string array that you then split manually, e.g. something like `"additionalInfomation": {SS: ["key#value", "key#value"] }`

Comment: it's okay I solved it. `additionalInformation: { L: [ {SS: ["", ""] }, {SS: ["", ""] } ] }`

Comment: I stand corrected, I had overlooked the `L` (List) and the `M` (Map)  [Attribute Values](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_AttributeValue.html) (see also the DynamoDB [Data Types](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.NamingRulesDataTypes.html#HowItWorks.DataTypes))

Comment: Thanks. That helped a lot! I wished the aws documentation had more examples 